# How can i change opacity on my dropdown menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

im very new to this and learning as i build!
On my store page, all the drop down menus are transparent so its hard to read the text,

https://pocketcardgrading.co.uk/product/professor-oni-water-colour-painting/
ive managed to edit it with inspector, but i cannot work out what css id need to implement it

```
<select id="professor-oni-painting" class="hasCustomSelect" name="attribute_professor-oni-painting" data-attribute_name="attribute_professor-oni-painting" data-show_option_none="yes" style="appearance: menulist-button; width: 451px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 34px; font-size: 14px;"
```

thats what i used to edit the opacity, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `opacity: 0` that's making your text transparent, as well as the container, so you need to omit that and make the background color of the container same as the site see Screenshot

[image]

Comment: thanks, i can do it in the inspector, i just cant work out how to switch it with css, i thought it would be something like 'appearance: Menulist-button {opacity: 1 }'

Comment: in the code example you published there's a `opacity` property on it, you can just change those styles to be what you can do in the inspector specifically 

```html
style="appearance: menulist-button; width: 451px; position: absolute; background-color: red; color: white; font-weight: bold; height: 34px; font-size: 14px;"

```

Comment: im sorry for sounding really silly, as ive only just started, im only really familiar with making changes using the custom css on the wordpress editor, how would i implement this? thanks for your time

Comment: not exactly sure how wordpress handles things, but if you have access to css files then just locate those styles and edit them